# Distribution of partial sums of a $L^2$-transformed Gaussian Process

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Our assumptions are: $X_t$ is a stationary sequence of standard normal random variables such that $\gamma _X (k)\sim L_{\gamma}(k)k^{2d-1}$ with $d \in (0,1/2)$, where $L_\gamma (k)$ is a slowly varying function. Let $Y_t:=G(X_t)$ with a real function $G$ such that $\mathbb{E}(G(X_1))=0$ and $\mathbb{E}(G(X_1)^2)<\infty$. 
What can we now say about the distribution of the following sum

$$S_n:=\sum_{j=1}^{n}Y_{j}$$

if the hermite rank of $G$ is 1? Is $S_n$ normal?